# focus and unfoucs an element of div with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make to container where when i click on an element of div1 and that div1 focus and div1 height increase and when the element of div1 is unfocus or nonfocus then div1 height return in previous style. Here I make an snippet but it is not working. Please can someone help me how could i do this ?I am using jquery framework..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".two").focus(function() {

    $(".one").css({
      'height': '400px',
      '-webkit-box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
      '-moz-box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
      'box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)'
    });

  });

});
```

```css
    .one {
      background-color: #f2c133;
      border: 3px solid #ccc;
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .two {
      width: 80px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #a1b2c3;
      color: #000;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex="0" class="one">
  <div class="two">

    click me

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".two").focus(function() {
    $(".one").addClass('isfocus');
    
    $(".one").focus(function() {
     $(".one").addClass('isfocus');
    });
  
    
  });
  
  $(".one").focusout(function() {
     $(".one").removeClass('isfocus');
  });
 
   
 $(".root").focus(function() {
   $(".one").removeClass('isfocus');
   $(".one").unbind();
  });
 
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: #f2c133;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.two {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #a1b2c3;
  color: #000;
}

.isfocus {
      height: 300px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body><div tabindex="4" class="root">
   <div tabindex="3" class="one">
  <div tabindex="2" class="two">

    click me

  </div>

</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724586/focusout-should-go-out-when-click-outside-of-main-div

Answer (score 1):

Please note that including jQuery more than once can cause some nasty errors.

You can achieve this required effect from the code below:

```
var $one = $( '.one' ),
    $two = $( '.two' );

var styleObj = {
    'height'             : '300px',
    '-webkit-box-shadow' : '2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
    'box-shadow'         : '2px 2px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)'
};

var addStyle = function() {
    $one.css( styleObj );
};

var removeStyle = function() {
    $one.removeAttr( 'style' );
};

$two.on({
    'mouseenter' : addStyle,
    'foucsin'    : addStyle,
    'mouseleave' : removeStyle,
    'foucsout'   : removeStyle,
});
```

JS Fiddle Demo Link: http://jsfiddle.net/_vijaydev/nh7vb32r/

Comment: i have four link of jquery in my html head one is min seconde is normal third is ui query and ui min. can cause this  ?

Comment: Yeah, don't include `jquery` more than once. You can use either the normal or min., preferred min; since smaller file.

The same logic goes for `jquery-ui` too.

Comment: so i should use min lib of jqueries  ?

Comment: Yeah you can download and compare and see that the min files are way more smaller than the full file. So using min files will make you pages load faster, especially someone on poor connection.

Comment: isnt' min file contain less code then normal? if i use only min and that min file cannot have that code which i want, isnt like it  ?

Comment: "min" contains the same code as that of full, except the white spaces are removed and the code uglified, meaning the variable are changed to single chars. Have no worries "min" file will work just like the full file.

Comment: ok ty sir can i have ur skype or add me on skype and ur code isnt working on focus. its working like hover. when i put mouse on it div height increse

Comment: Yeah we need to use `tabindex` and replace `foucs` and `blur` events with `focusin` and `focusout`, respectively. Updated main comment and JS fiddle demo code.

Sorry no skype.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this works

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">click me</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one {
    background-color: #f2c133;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
.two {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #a1b2c3;
    color: #000;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".two").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".one").animate({
            'height': "300px",
                '-webkit-box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
                '-moz-box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
                'box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)'
        });
        $(".one").mouseleave(function () {
            $(".one").animate({
                'height': "50px",
                    '-webkit-box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
                    '-moz-box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
                    'box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)'
            });
        });


    });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4c21ydbw/1/)

Comment: this is work like  hover.  i said like on animate on focus and unfocus come to orignal/previous style.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".two").focus(function() {
    $(".one").addClass('isfocus');
  });

  $(".two").focusout(function() {
    $(".one").removeClass('isfocus');
  });

});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: #f2c133;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.two {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #a1b2c3;
  color: #000;
}

.isfocus {
      height: 300px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
   <div tabindex="1" class="one">
  <div tabindex="2" class="two">

    click me

  </div>

</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is not working how i aspacted  it foucus out when u click on main div i dont  want like this.. please help me